# Log Search terms/keywords in Solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, jetty

I developed a search tool using Solr; I want to look at the search terms used by other people when they search. Please suggest me a way.

This might be a duplicate of [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108676/logging-search-keywords-in-solr-lucene) 
However, the Solr Jetty ./logs/*request.log files are empty in my case which I am not sure why.

Comment: With version 4.3 there have been changes in the way Solr does its' logging. Have a read here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging probably that helps you to get the request.logs again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SOLR4.4.0 with default Jetty setup. I can see following lines in solr.log file under logs folder.

INFO  - 2013-10-01 12:33:08.319; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/terms params={timestamp=1380610985478&limit=10&terms.fl=name&q=*:&wt=velocity&v.template=suggest &terms.sort=count&terms.prefix=*:} status=0 QTime=1069

INFO  - 2013-10-01 12:33:12.027; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/browse params={q=*:*} hits=28 status=0 QTime=4796

Hope This Helps!!!!