# Solr Search terms logs

Tags: solr, lucene, jetty

I wanted to log Solr queries users are submitting. I could generate request logs from the solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111984/1830069) using Jetty.

Now, that I have the request logs (sample pasted below). Can anyone explain what does this mean q=**%2A%3A%2A** ?

*0.0.0.0  -  [14/Jan/2014:15:29:52 +0000] "GET /solr-nutch/hbasecollection/select?facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=source&facet.field=type&hl=true&hl.fl=title%2Ccontent&hl.simple.pre=%3Cstrong%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fstrong%3E&hl.fragsize=300&fl=%2A%2Cscore&version=1.2&wt=json&json.nl=map&**q=%2A%3A%2A**&start=0&rows=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 114440*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is [Percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You may use [URL Decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to get the actual query. In your case, it's `*:*`.

Comment: Can you think of a best way to parse those logs to just spit out the terms in "q="?

Comment: You can try extending default logging of Jetty server and automatically decode all percent data, but technically you will be incorrect as the logger logs real HTTP traffic - this is what is being actually sent over the wire. How to do this? - I'm no Jetty expert, but http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging seems like a good start. Anyway, this should probably be raised as a separate question.

Comment: sure. That's what I thought. Thank you!